# Google cloud task queues not running in parallel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I have a project in google cloud where there are 2 task queues: `process-request` to receive requests and process them, `send-result` to send the result of the processed request to another server. They are both running on an instance called `remote-processing`

My problem is that I see the tasks being enqueued in `send-result` but they are only executed after the `process-request` queue is empty and has processed all requests.
This is the instance config:

```
instance_class: B4

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 8
```

Here is the queue config:

```
- name: send-result
  max_concurrent_requests: 20
  rate: 1/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 10
    min_backoff_seconds: 5
    max_backoff_seconds: 20
  target: remote-processing

- name: process-request
  bucket_size: 50
  max_concurrent_requests: 10
  rate: 10/s
  target: remote-processing
```

Clarification : I don't need for the queues to run in an specific order, but I find it very strange that it looks like the insurance only runs one queue at a time, so it will only run the tasks in another queue after its done with the current queue.

Answer (score 2):

over what period of time is this all happening?

how long does a `process-request` task take to run vs a `send-result` task

One thing that sticks out is that your `rate` for `process-request` is much higher than your `rate` for `send-result`. So maybe a couple `send-result` tasks ARE squeezing off, but it then hits the `rate` cap and has to run `process-request` tasks instead.

Same note for `bucket_size`. The `bucket_size` for `process-request` is huge compared to it's `rate`:

> The bucket size limits how fast the queue is processed when many tasks
>   are in the queue and the rate is high. The maximum value for bucket
>   size is 500. This allows you to have a high rate so processing starts
>   shortly after a task is enqueued, but still limit resource usage when
>   many tasks are enqueued in a short period of time.
>
> If you don't specify bucket_size for a queue, the default value is 5.
>   We recommend that you set this to a larger value because the default
>   size might be too small for many use cases: the recommended size is
>   the processing rate divided by 5 (rate/5).

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref

Also, by setting `max_instances: 8` does a big backlog of work build-up in these queues?

Let's try a two things:

1. set `bucket_size` and `rate` to be the same for both `process-request` and `send-result`. If fixes it, then start fiddling with the values to get the desired balance
2. bump up `max_instances: 8` to see if removing that bottleneck fixes it